# Compare two arrays of single characters and return the difference?

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

I need to be able to compare, and get the difference, between two arrays containing single character letters appearing multiple times in each array.

Example:

`arr_a = ["E", "F", "X", "O", "U", "R", "T", "I", "D", "E", "N", "G", "Ø", "M", "F", "Æ", "A", "M", "Ø", "R", "Å", "N", "D", "E", "D", "R", "A", "_", "S", "E", "L", "U", "V"]`

`arr_b = ["E", "F", "X", "O", "U", "R", "T", "I", "D", "E", "N", "G", "Ø", "M", "F", "Æ", "A", "M", "Ø", "R", "Å", "N", "D", "E", "D", "R", "A", "G", "S", "E", "L", "U", "V", "O", "I", "A", "R", "E", "S", "E"]`

I've tried quite a few found on google, but none return the expected result. The problem seems to be with algorithms that loop through each letter, and then manipulate the result. I need something that take into account the case that each letter can appear multiple times, and calculate the difference of how many times that actually happens.

Any hints?

Comment: please add the result, you expect, and the code, you tried.

Comment: I think you want arra=[aabc] ; arrb=[abcde] - the diff is [ade] , is it what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could check each character at the same position and return only the parts who are different.

```js
function getDifference(first, second) {
    var min = Math.min(first.length, second.length),
        i = 0,
        result = [];

    while (i < min) {
        if (first[i] !== second[i]) {
            result.push(first[i], second[i]);
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return result.concat(first.slice(min), second.slice(min));
}

var arr_a = ["E", "F", "X", "O", "U", "R", "T", "I", "D", "E", "N", "G", "Ø", "M", "F", "Æ", "A", "M", "Ø", "R", "Å", "N", "D", "E", "D", "R", "A", "_", "S", "E", "L", "U", "V"],
    arr_b = ["E", "F", "X", "O", "U", "R", "T", "I", "D", "E", "N", "G", "Ø", "M", "F", "Æ", "A", "M", "Ø", "R", "Å", "N", "D", "E", "D", "R", "A", "G", "S", "E", "L", "U", "V", "O", "I", "A", "R", "E", "S", "E"];

console.log(getDifference(arr_a, arr_b));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This seem to return 9 values even though the count varies with only 7.

Comment: @blaasvaer, please add the wanted result to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a code just like you needed.

```js
arr_a = ["E", "F", "X", "O", "U", "R", "T", "I", "D", "E", "N", "G", "Ø", "M", "F", "Æ", "A", "M", "Ø", "R", "Å", "N", "D", "E", "D", "R", "A", "_", "S", "E", "L", "U", "V"]

arr_b = ["E", "F", "X", "O", "U", "R", "T", "I", "D", "E", "N", "G", "Ø", "M", "F", "Æ", "A", "M", "Ø", "R", "Å", "N", "D", "E", "D", "R", "A", "G", "S", "E", "L", "U", "V", "O", "I", "A", "R", "E", "S", "E"]

a_json = {};
b_json = {};

arr_a.forEach(function (element){
 if(a_json.hasOwnProperty(element)){
  a_json[element]++;
 }
 else{
  a_json[element] = 1;
 }
});

arr_b.forEach(function (element){
 if(b_json.hasOwnProperty(element)){
  b_json[element]++;
 }
 else{
  b_json[element] = 1;
 }
});

diff_json = {};
keys_a = Object.keys(a_json);

keys_a.forEach(function(key_a){
 if(b_json.hasOwnProperty(key_a)){
  diff_json[key_a] = Math.abs(a_json[key_a] - b_json[key_a] );
 }
});

console.log(diff_json)
```

Comment: @blaasvaer Did you find this answer useful?? Is this what you meant ??

Answer (score -1):

What about transforming them into one (char -> number) object?

```
 var keys={};
 arr1.forEach(function(e){
   keys[e]=keys[e]||0;
   keys[e]++;
 }
 arr2.forEach(function(e){
   keys[e]=keys[e]||0;
   keys[e]--;
 }
console.log(keys);
```

Keys will contain the difference between the appearance of a key in the two arrays. Something like:

```
"A":0, // A appears equal in both
"B":1, //B appears one more time in arr1 then in arr2
"C":-2 //C appears 2 times more in arr2 then in arr1
```

Or if you want to find the differences in arr2 compared to arr1 as an array of chars, do:

```
var diff=arr2.map((e,i)=>e==arr1[i]?undefined:e);
```